# Edit keyboard shortcuts in Juypter Notebooks

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, jupyter-notebook

I am new to Juypter notebooks and trying to edit and re-bind keys to actions. I tried to add another shortcut but seems like I made a mistake in entering the right terms so not I see the following (see screenshot). I tried deleting the "^Undefined" shortcut by clicking on the cross but it seem Juypter doenst save the "deletion" so it keeps reappearing. How does one save this edit / rebind ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the path `nbconfig/notebook.json` inside the [configuration directory](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use/jupyter-directories.html#id1).

It's a JSON file, you should be able to edit it with any text editor. In particular, the key bindings should be in the `keys.commands.bind` dictionary.

Example:

```json
{
  "keys": {
    "command": {
      "bind": {
        "ctrl-xxx": "jupyter-notebook:toggle-cell-rtl-layout" /* <-- delete this line! */
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: (I used `fatrace` to find the path of the file.)